# Sql Error - .NET 4 - Simple desktop application

Tags: c#, sql, datasource

Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010, tagert framework = .NET 4 Client Profile

I'm creating a desktop application, completely local, it doesn't access servers. For that i'm using a .MDF SQL Server database and LINQ. Everything works fine on my machine, however, when i deploy it, the following error is shown when i try to connect to the database:

***A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)***

Here are info which might be useful for you guys:

```
Project file structure:  
\myapp.exe  
\data\bdapepuc.mdf
```

---

```
Connection string: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\BDApepuc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

The machine to be the deployed only has the .NET 4 Client Profile installed, nothing else.

Thanks for your help, this error is really spanking me. Change suggestions are welcome too

Edit:

I corrected the connection string, i had pasted the wrong one, please check it.

**So far i tried (including tips from you guys here) without success:**

- Relative path, like:
  AttachDbFilename=\Data\BDApepuc.mdf
- Installing sql server compact 3.5 SP2

Comment: i see you connection string has the following full path for the DB C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjLuciana4\ProjLuciana4\ .... does the machine u are deploying to have this same folder structure where your project is being deplyed?

Comment: Yea i pasted the wrong one, its corrected now, check it again please.

Comment: Refer Han's answer below. I think that will help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> completely local, it doesn't access servers

It does, it accesses a SQL Server Express server.  You'll have to deploy that as well.  You could include the bootstrapper for it in your Setup project.  Or just download it [from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=58CE885D-508B-45C8-9FD3-118EDD8E6FFF&displaylang=en).

Comment: i'm trying to find the bootstrapper, i dont want, if possible, to add a 80mb file to my tiny project. I will try that anyway.

Comment: Project + Setup Properties,  Prerequisites button, tick "SQL Server 2008 Express".

Comment: Did you actually create a Setup project?  The template is under "Other Project Types" + "Setup and Deployment".  Not available on the Express edition.

Comment: I found it now. It turns out that for me to "tick" the Sql Server 2008 Express i need to tick "NET 3.5 SP1" and "Windows Installer 4.5". Because of that now the user has to make a gigantic download in order to install, very sad. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: If this is some kind of applet that users can download from the Internet, instead of a line-of-business app, then using SQL Server Express is not appropriate.  Your user isn't going to be happy getting it installed on their machine, it has non-trivial runtime (and install) requirements.  Use SQL Server Compact instead.  Or simple files.

Comment: Yes, im trying that now, i will manually convert my sql express db to a sql compact one, and then use sqlmetal to generate the files, i hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you just have an invalid `AttachDbFilename` - unless your target deployment machine actually has VS2010 installed, and your project on it.

The path to the MDF needs to be a relative path, and then you can change the properties of the MDF in your VS project to copy it to the output directory.

Comment: I get the same error when i use a relative path such as:
AttachDbFilename=\Data\BDApepuc.mdf
or
AttachDbFilename=Data\BDApepuc.mdf